# How to replace tf.feature_column.bucketized_column+tf.feature_column.embedding_column with some faster api composition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

We've built a Wide and Deep model with hundreds of input feature_columns defined as:

```py
    embedding_numeric_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key)
    bucketized_col = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(embedding_numeric_col, boundaries=boundaries_name_to_boundaries[feature_name_to_boundaries_name[key]])
    embedding_col = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(bucketized_col, dimension=embed_dim, combiner='mean')
    embedding_columns.append(embedding_col)
```

The online inference latency performance is poor. So we've tried to sample some tensorflow pipeline, it turns out that the model spend so much time on operations like `Reshape`, `Shape`, `ExpandDim`, `Cast` and etc.
[image]

So we inspect the generated model structure by netron, and read tensorflow source code, it turns out that `tf.feature_column.bucketize_column` generate much more operations than we expected.
[image]
[image]

So i wonder is there any chance that we can replace the `bucketized_column` + `embedding_column` API composition with other faster alternative, e.g. raw `bucketize` op plus `tf.one_hot` and `embedding_column`. If so, how to write it properly?